# Access and edit files in runtime android app

Tags: android, file, unity-game-engine, local, unityscript

My game is fed by parameters from a text file.
When I run the game in Unity, I can set the file path to my desktop or whatever and that works perfectly.

The problem is that when I run the game on an android device, I have to set the file path to some local folder in the device, a folder which I'll have access to.

How can I do that?

I want the file to be part of the .apk file.

I'm sure there's a way for doing that, yet could not find some relevant information on the internet.

Comment: If your looking to add files to apk, then you can have a `raw` folder inside `res` folder in android project. You can add files to raw folder and access them.

Comment: And what's the path I have to use? 
To what absolute path this path equals? "./"

Comment: `getResources().openRawResource(R.id.your_text_file_name_without_extenstion)`

Comment: Hmm.. this is in Java right? I'm writing the scripts in C# (Unity...).

Thanks again !

Comment: Note that nothing contained in your apk is modifiable - to get that, you have to store an initial version in the apk and then copy it somewhere modifiable, such as your internal storage folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem as your, I had to load some Translation Text Files in my game.

You can save the text file in the `Resources` folder. Then load it at runtime with `Resources.Load("folderInsideResourcesFolder\textFile")`. The `Resources` folder will be packaged in the APK.

You can find more info here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html